# How avoid extra quotes added within a loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, double-quotes

When performing a loop on a table in which a value has ", I get those quotes doubled such as:
initial input: 'test AND "test"'
output in the loop: 'test AND ""test""'

How to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
   id int,
   criteria VARCHAR (255)
);

INSERT INTO roles (id, criteria) VALUES (1, 'test AND "test"');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_quote()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
sample varchar;
rec   record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT * FROM roles
    LOOP
        sample:= rec;
    END LOOP;
   RETURN sample;
END
$$;

SELECT * FROM test_quote();
```

Expected result: `(1,"test AND "test"")`
Actual result: `(1,"test AND ""test""")`

Does anyone have an idea how to get the expected behaviour here?

Comment: Your varchar is actually a record. Why don't you return an integer for the id and a varchar for the criteria?

Comment: `"test AND "test""` is not a valid text literal. Double quotes are the expected escape syntax

Comment: Is this your actual code, or what does your function do? (Because if it was, you shouldn't be using a loop but simply `LIMIT 1`)

Answer (score 0):

Found it, indeed, the issue is from the conversion from record to varchar.

I can directly pass the column from the rec like:

sample:= rec.criteria;

(I didn't know that we could do that)

So, that gives:

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
   id int,
   criteria VARCHAR (255)
);

INSERT INTO roles (id, criteria) VALUES (1, 'test AND "test"');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_quote()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
sample varchar;
rec   record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT * FROM roles
    LOOP
        sample := rec.criteria;
    END LOOP;
   RETURN sample;
END
$$;

SELECT * FROM test_quote();
```

Thx guys!